# Cascading delete error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have coded a `MVC5` Internet Application with cascading deletes, and am getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestDeleteForeignKeyReferences.Models.Room]' to type 'TestDeleteForeignKeyReferences.Models.Room'.
```

Here is my context class:

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<House> houses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> rooms { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.rooms)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Here is my `House` class:

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; }

    public House()
    {
        rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}
```

Here is my `Room` class:

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual House house { get; set; }
}
```

The error occurs when trying to add a `House` to the database at the following Create code:

```
db.houses.Add(house);
```

If I have no `OnModelCreating` method in the context class, the error does not occur.

Can I please have some help to get this code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a one (house) to many (rooms) relation with optional principal (house is optional on room). The configuration should be like.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
        .HasMany(x => x.rooms)
        .WithOptional(x => x.house)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```